# Using a reference genome not on ensembl for Snakemake?

Tags: snakemake, rna-seq

I am wanting to process and analyze RNAseq data for a species that does not have a genome on ensembl. My lab does have an assembly and annotation of it, and it's being processed by genbank but is not public yet. Is there a way to use my own reference genome in snakemake instead of pointing to one from ensembl?

I'm using this snakemake workflow:
https://github.com/snakemake-workflows/rna-seq-kallisto-sleuth

And wanting to change the reference genome input for the config.yaml file at this point:

```
ref:
    # ensembl species name
    species: homo_sapiens
    # ensembl release version
    release: "104"
    # genome build
    build: GRCh38
    # pfam release to use for annotation of domains in differential splicing analysis
    pfam: "33.0"
    # Choose strategy for selecting representative transcripts for each gene.
    # Possible values:
    #   - canonical (use the canonical transcript from ensembl, only works for human at the moment)
    #   - mostsignificant (use the most significant transcript)
    #   - path/to/any/file.txt (a path to a file with ensembl transcript IDs to use;
    #     the user has to ensure that there is only one ID per gene given)
    representative_transcripts: canonical
  ontology:
    # gene ontology to download, used e.g. in goatools
    gene_ontology: "http://current.geneontology.org/ontology/go-basic.obo"
```

Comment: I think you are leaving out some details. Snakemake is very generalized for writing workflows and out of the box doesn't know about Ensembl. It sounds like you are maybe using a particular workflow, maybe from [The Snakemake Wrappers repository](https://snakemake-wrappers.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html)? It looks like from the limited information you provide it is set up to provide information yourself at least in one aspect. See the third entry under 'Possible values'. I would suspect the answer to your title is definitely 'Yes' but cannot tell much more because your post lacks details.

Comment: Thank you for the points of clarification Wayne, I added more info about what workflow I'm using hopefully that clarifies things!

Comment: Thanks. That certainly helps. And the answer is in there on how to do it. I'll take a shot at covering an outline. Maybe someone else will also now be able to add more advice with what you've added now.

Answer (score 0):

This outline may help you see how to adapt the workflow to provide your own resources:

Effectively, you'll complete up to step #3 as written in [the Usage](https://snakemake.github.io/snakemake-workflow-catalog/?usage=snakemake-workflows%2Frna-seq-kallisto-sleuth). Then in addition to edits discussed in the Usage in `config`, you'll want to produce edits in the files also found in `workflow`. And add in to `resources` directory all the equivalents of the files that would normally be fetched from ensembl necessary for all the parts of the workflow you care about. Keep in mind you may wish to skip some parts if you don't have the necessary, equivalent input files.

To make it more reproducible you'll probably want to fork the repo and actually make the edits in your fork, i.e., upstream of what you'll deploy. And then in the `snakedeploy` step use your fork as the URL and not the main one. That should get you the rules with your edits. In fact, you could even alter the stuff in `config` so you have a record, too. The idea with the fork is that you have a place to point out all the changes you made, and even perhaps the version of the config files, you use. But that is just an option to consider to make it easier to track everything.

No matter how you go about it, you'll want to effectively change what is in `workflow/rules/ref.smk` ([code on the main repo](https://github.com/snakemake-workflows/rna-seq-kallisto-sleuth/blob/main/workflow/rules/ref.smk)) to not run for the files you are going to place into `resources` by hand instead of having them be obtained from Ensembl. So just remove those rules. I don't know enough about this to know if this means **all the rules in `ref.smk`** or not. If it does mean all the rules, you can make things easier and just comment out the line `include: "rules/ref.smk"` in `workflow/Snakefile` ([code in the main repo](https://github.com/snakemake-workflows/rna-seq-kallisto-sleuth/blob/main/workflow/Snakefile)). As a by-product of these changes keep in mind for the equivalent portions of the ref section in `config.yaml` what you put there is moot.

Keep in mind that `representative_transcripts` section already has a way to provide a path so you can use that part `as-is` under the `resources:` & `ref:` section in `config.yaml`.

---

If things aren't apparent and you want to be cautious, you do this adapting gradually. First try to get it working "as-is" then substitute in one piece at a time. It will certainly break downstream steps as you do it, but it lets you see more clearly what is happening with the parts you are adapting as you go along.

---

UPDATE:
I did find you can circumvent running the rule `get_transcript_info` (and associated script `get-transcript-info.R`) by pointing `representative_transcripts`:  in the `config.yaml` at a `.tsv` file with the transcript to gene assignments and write that `.tsv` at an `.rds` file and rename the `.rds` version & place it in the 'resources' directory as `transcript-info.rds`. That way you can leave the rule `get_transcript_inf`o (and associated script `get-transcript-info.R`) intact in the workflow yet skip the rule when you don't have 'canonical' and 'mostsignificant' assignments & want a custom

Comment: Wayne, 
Thank you so much for taking the time to answer! I have everything working up to step 3 as you referenced, and I've copied my genome and annotation files into the resources directory. 

I'm still a little lost about what edits to make in the usage and workflow files, specifically workflow/rules/ref.smk

What can I add or change to make those rules reference my genome and annotation files instead of ensembl? If you have any recommendations for resources to help me read this file more fluently that would be appreciated as well, if you can't help me rewrite it specifically. Thank you!

Comment: I've sort of exhausted what I can specify without seeing particulars more. In [my profile over at Github](https://github.com/fomightez), my email is available on the left side.

Comment: I updated the answer with a way to circumvent  the rule `get_transcript_info` (and associated script `get-transcript-info.R`).